# Avoid duplicate file uploads - Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

In Rails 4.0 Project, I am using multiple file upload plugin. Right now it is working via ajax request. 
Now, I want to avoid duplicate file upload and it should show proper validation message. Also as soon file upload page needs to refresh. How can I validate duplicate files and refresh the page?

Reference : http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php#multi

Paperclip gem version is

```
paperclip (3.5.2, 2.3.11, 2.3.8)
```

In views,

```
<%= simple_form_for(@file, :as=>"file", :url=>create_files_path, :html=>{:multipart => true, :autocomplete=>"off"}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :document, :as=>:file, :label =>false, :required => true %>
<% end %>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#file_document").uploadFile({
   url:"<%= create_files_path %>",
   multiple:true,
   showDone: false,
   showProgress: true,
   showError:true
 });
</script>
```

Comment: duplicate by it contents or name?

Comment: need to check by file content

Comment: The closest is filename, type and size, you cannot check by contents easily especially if its binary.

Comment: If filename is different but the inside content is same how to recognize it? Here file is text file not a binary file.

Comment: How can I check the duplicate file using name?

Comment: You can calculate the MD5 (`md5sum`) for each file and compare them. The file name does not matter to calculate the MD5. So you can get the same files even if the file name was changed

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Bjoernsen comment on MD5 digest I found this blog post which is also comparing files on S3. I believe this is also how git works using SHA-1 hashes.

Again, Thanks to @Bjoersen for pointing it out. I learnt something.

http://bytesofpi.com/post/24636043214/comparing-two-files-via-md5-hash-on-amazon-s3-using